# How do I format an internal hard drive so that FreeBSD, Linux and Windows can all access it?

Tags: linux, filesystems, windows, freebsd

I'd like to know how to format a 2 TB hard drive so that FreeBSD, Linux and Windows can all access it and write to it. I've tried using my own brain on this one and making a singular partition on it and creating a FAT32 file system on it, as I know a FAT32 file system on a USB means virtually all operating systems can utilize it. The problem is that Windows 10 doesn't detect it anymore.

Comment: Use [exfat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExFAT)

Comment: Are you sure? I did it and Windows 10 doesn't seem to recognize it. The only drive listed for it is C:\, which is my SSD.

Comment: Is this to allow several machines to access the disk or are you multi-booting a single machine? If it's several machines, set up a Samba share.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [UDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Disk_Format). It is finicky to get settings that all OSes are happy to deal with though. The [`format-udf`](https://github.com/JElchison/format-udf) is a reliable way to get the blocksizes right. (Note: FreeBSD only has read-only support, and only for older UDF versions)

It is widely supported, doesn't have FAT32's filesize limitations or exFAT's patent issues. It supports Unix-style permissions.

Size limit is 2TiB though, unless the disk uses native 4K sectors.

Windows XP can read, but won't write to UDF on hard-disks. Later Windows versions has better support. (FreeBSD seems to be lagging behind with read-only support, for ancient versions only though...)

FAT32 remains an option (your issue with it is likely [quickly rectified in Disk Management](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/disk-management/change-a-drive-letter) or by fixing the partition type byte (assuming MBR)).

Answer (score 1):

Use NTFS. exFAT isn't supported in FreeBSD, as well as ext4, which is also unsupported in Windows. However, both FreeBSD and Linux have decent implementation of NTFS via `ntfs-3g`.

Comment: Something seriously funky must be going on as I just created a NTFS filesystem on this 2TB hard drive with ntfs-3g, and Windows 10 doesn't recognize it. I know NTFS is the filesystem of Windows 10, but still it's not detected.

Comment: Fire up `diskmgmt.msc` and see if Windows can see the drive at least.

Comment: I gave up thanks to that and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/469856/how-to-delete-a-git-repo-with-submodule-from-ntfs-partition-and-then-git-clone-i and decided to simply use a ext4 partition and say to .... with Windows.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using exFAT for my external drive. For me exFAT still widely compatible then other FS. I've been using it for Linux, Windows 8/10, FreeBSD and macOS X. Problem will arise if the drive connected to FreeBSD so I have to follow this excellent tutorial [HowTo mount a extFAT filesystem on FreeBSD](https://dbudwm.wordpress.com/2014/03/28/howto-mount-a-extfat-filesystem-on-freebsd/). It work Flawlessly, READ and WRITE all works.

To format exFAT on windows 10 is easy just do these simple step and you're done:

- open cmd
- type `format F: /FS:exFAT`, change F: with your external drive letter.